# What does it mean if "f(x) is not equal g(x) only at a finite number of points"

Tags: functions

I am just confused on how this can happen as if the functions deviate at any point would there not be an infinte amount of deviations in between?

i.e say at x1 and x3 they have the same value but at x2 they have a different value, would there not be an infinte amount of different points then when you draw the function?

(f and g are bounded and continuous functions)

Comment: If these were continuous functions on the real line, say, then this would not be possible.  But of course you don't say that they are continuous.

Comment: so then does that mean f and g are discontinuous functions or that they are continuous functions but not on the real line?

Comment: What you wrote is very vague.  Presumably, your context tells you what the domain of these functions is, right?

Comment: Let f, g ∈ B[a, b] and suppose that f(x) != g(x) only at a finite
number of points. Then (lower riemann integral of f) = (lower riemann integral of g)

Comment: And presumably the context also tells you what $B[a,b]$ means, yes?

Comment: That just means that f and g are bounded between a and b

Comment: Ok, but again:  your source will tell you what the domain of these functions is.  I'd guess it's the real line, but your source will tell you.  And I am guessing that there is no assumption of continuity.

Comment: This is just a theory from my lecture notes, a while back it said we will be working with continuous functions unless stated otherwise and it hasnt said we arent, and it hasnt said the domain anywhere

Comment: Well, we really can't guess what your lecturer was thinking of.  Again, continuous functions of a real variable can't differ on a finite set only.

Comment: "I am just confused on how this can happen as if the functions deviate at any point would there not be an infinte amount of deviations in between?"  If the functions are continuous that would be true.  But we are not talking about continuous functions.  Consider.  $f(x) = 2x + 5$ and $g(x) = \begin{cases} 15&\text{if }x=7\\ 2x+5&\text{if }x\ne 7\end{cases}$.  $f(x)=g(x)$ whenever $x\ne 7$ but $f(7)\ne g(7)$.  So the functions differ at exactly one point.

Comment: Can you tell use just what the theorem said in total rather than just this one phrase.  If you are making a theorem about function in general and there's a possibility that the functions differ in a finite number of places (which can only happen if they aren't cont) I think that is a valid excpetion to "assume continuous unless stated otherwise".  We *can't* state otherwise as we don't know, and we can't say thereom cant have them differ finitely if they are cont which we assume because they might *not* be cont.

Comment: This is the entire theorem "Let f, g ∈ B[a, b] and suppose that f(x) != g(x) only at a finite number of points. Then (lower riemann integral of f) = (lower riemann integral of g)"